# How can I get my linear-gradient over an image the same size as the image in css?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a simple header and want to use an image with a linear-gradient over the top. Of course I want these both to be the same size. I want the size of the header to be 80%. When I write my code, as follows, the image becomes the size I set (80%), but the linear-gradient covers the width of the entire content of the page, and overflows out the sides of the 80% image. The only resolution is to set background-size to cover, then they both cover the page together. But I want to be able to control the size of the image and its gradient. (Note:switching the size to px also did not help) Why are they functioning separate from each other when they are applied?

```html
<style>
.full-page-wrapper{
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0 ,0, 0.7)), 
   url(address) center no-repeat;
   background-size:80%;
}
</style>

<div class="full-page-wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrapper">  
      <h1 class="title">Example</h1>
      <p class="description">Example content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to also add no-repeat to the gradient and make it center too: `linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0 ,0, 0.7)) center no-repeat, 
   url(address) center no-repeat`

Comment: Thank you! Would not have guessed that, I thought the one at the end covered both.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your background like below:

```
.full-page-wrapper{
   background: 
     linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0 ,0, 0.7)) center no-repeat, 
     url(address) center no-repeat;
   background-size:80%;
}
```

Note how gradient also need a position and `no-repeat` otherwise it will get repeated and the position will be the default one.